# Integer input for operator

Tags: java

I need to know how to fetch the input for the operator for this simple program I am making that does this; the person enters a number, and if it's greater than 10, it displays the message "it worked". Where it says "NEED INPUT" is where I need the system scanner entry to go.

Operators class:

```
class Classes {

private int Numbers;

public Classes() {}

Classes(String namez) {
    Numbers = Numbers;
}


public int getNumbers() {
    return Numbers;
}

public void setNumbers(int numberz) {
    if((Integer.parseInt(INPUT HERE.getText().toString()) )<=10) {
        System.out.print("It worked.");
    }
}
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneTwoThree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Classes.Numbers(keyboard.nextLine());
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the static method `NameOne`?

Comment: This does not even compile. What is INPUT HERE. ?

Comment: I need to know how to get the Scanner input to go to the operator that gives the output if it is less than 10. I updated the post as well.

Comment: @RiddleAkane, it is still not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @RiddleAkane , see my answer and let me know if this is somewhere close to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package mavens.dais.test;

public class ClassesTest {

   private int Numbers;

   public ClassesTest() {}

   ClassesTest(String namez) {
      Numbers = Integer.parseInt(namez);
   }


   public int getNumbers() {
      return Numbers;
   }

    public void setNumbers(int numberz) {
        if(numberz > 10){
            System.out.print("It is worked.");
        }else{
            System.out.print("It is not worked.");
        }
    }


}



package mavens.dais.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneTwoThre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        new ClassesTest().setNumbers(Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine()));
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explained all of the issues and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
Classes.Numbers(keyboard.nextLine());
```

this should be replaced by `Classes(keyboard.nextLine());` to begin with, in your class named `OneTwoThree`

Secondly

```
Classes(String namez) {
    Numbers = Numbers;
}
```

this seems pretty much wrong.

Should be replaced by something like

```
Classes(String namez) {
    Numbers = Integer.parseInt(namez); //if you are entering integers only through keyboard
}
```

As far as I could understand your question,

you can go like this then,

```
Classes(String namez) {
        Numbers = Integer.parseInt(namez); //if you are entering integers  only through keyboard

       performOperation(Numbers);// call a method you want,pass number as arg

    }


public static void performOperation(int num){
if(Numbers >10){
              //do stuff
            }
            else{
              //else part
            }
    }
}
```

*Also ,just as a good practice* you should name your variable `Numbers` to `number`.

I Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the String.

```
public static void testScanner() {
    try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        while (true) {
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            Handler.handleInput(input);
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
}

static class Handler {
    public Handler() {

    }

    public static void handleInput(String input) {
        try {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if (x <= 10) {
                System.out.println("It worked!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Aw, Id didn't work.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Hey, watch it buddy. Don't throw any letters in there, I don't like them.");
        }
    }
}
```